# How do I use variables when inserting an Excel formula using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get an Excel `If` formula to apply to all rows with content in a sheet. If the cell value entered after the macro is applied is `y`, then something appears in the next column, if it is `n` something else appears. It looks like this:

```
For Row = 2 To LastRow
        Cells(Row, 8).Formula = "=IF(""H"" & Row & ""="" ""Y"",""Included"",IF(""H"" & Row & ""="" ""N"",""SYS"", """"))"
    Next
```

I believe the issue is with where I putting the quotes and how many, but I can't figure that out for the life of me. I was able to get the formula to work when I chose a specific cell, ie. `H2`,  but the issue began when I tried to use a variable.

Any help or tips or references would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easier to replace tokens than to use concatenation, as it's easier to manage the quotes that way.

```
Const FRM As String  = "=IF(H<r>=""Y"",""Included"",IF(H<r>=""N"",""SYS"", """"))"
For Row = 2 To LastRow
    Cells(Row, 8).Formula = Replace(FRM, "<r>", Row
Next
```

Comment: GAMECHANGER. Thank you!